# JMeter: Variable to HTTP request

Tags: http, jmeter

In JMeter, I have a variable which contains HTTP request as it is (the method, URL, headers and payload). How can I send this HTTP request in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a single variable which represents full HTTP request contents in a textual form the easiest solution would be going for [HTTP Raw Request](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/RawRequest/) sampler.

Just put your variable into "Request Data" section and that would be it

[image: JMeter HTTP Raw Request]

You can install HTTP Raw Request sampler using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)